# Internet Explorer uploading file data as a String in Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, file-upload

Some random IE users (versions 6-8) aren't able to upload files. The data that comes in the POST is a String instead of a File object.

Has anyone seen this and have any insight into where the issue may be?

Valid upload:

`attachment_data: #<File:/tmp/RackMultipart7719-0>`

Invalid upload:

`attachment_data: "Soccer profile.doc"`

[UPDATE]

Some random IE users refers to 5 or 6 out of thousands. So, yes it's a multipart form. And it is already using Paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have :multipart => true in the form_for?